# How can I switch the focus for the pop-up window?

Tags: qt, qml

I encounter a problem which is that the pop-up window cannot get the focus when it is shown. I tried to use the activefocus function in main window, but it doesn't work. It is supposed that if I press the enter key, the pop-window will be closed. How can I get the focus for the pop-up window? Thanks.

```
...
GridView {
                   id:grid_main
                   anchors.fill: parent                       
                   focus: true
                   currentIndex: 0

                   model: FileModel{
                       id: myModel
                       folder: "c:\\folder"  
                       nameFilters: ["*.mp4","*.jpg"]
                   }

                   highlight: Rectangle { width: 80; height: 80; color: "lightsteelblue" }

                   delegate: Item {
                       width: 100; height: 100

                       Text {
                           anchors { top: myIcon.bottom; horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
                           text: fileName
                       }
                       MouseArea {
                           anchors.fill: parent
                           onClicked: {
                               parent.GridView.view.currentIndex = index    
                           }
                       }
                   }

                   Keys.onPressed: { //pop up window
                            if (event.key == 16777220) {//enter                                    
                                subWindow.show();                                    
                                subWindow.forceActiveFocus();
                                event.accepted = true;
                                grid_main.focus = false;
                            }
                   }
    }

   Window {
           id: subWindow

           Keys.onPressed: {
                    if (event.key == 16777220) {//press enter                           
                        subWindow.close();
                    }
           }
    }
...
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you suggest, providing the full program or minimizing the code length?

Comment: Minimise the program as much as possible while ensuring that it still reproduces your problem. Never post the full program unless it's really small.

Comment: Just a suggestion about *mcve*: post code that runs out of the box. Copy and paste the code you posted and see if it runs with `qmlscene`. If it doesn't, it is very unlikely that someone will bother fixing it to test it (i.e. adding imports, removing unnecessary ellipses, add an appropriate root element, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with some basics:

```
Keys.onPressed: { //pop up window
    if (event.key == 16777220) {//enter
        subWindow.show()
        ...
        event.accepted = true
    }
}
```

Not to mention how error-prone it is, just for the sake of readability, please don't hard-code enum values like `16777220`. Qt provides `Qt.Key_Return` and `Qt.Key_Enter` (typically located on the keypad) and more conveniently, `Keys.returnPressed` and `Keys.enterPressed` signal handlers. These convenience handlers even automatically set `event.accepted = true`, so you can replace the signal handler with a lot simpler version:

```
Keys.onReturnPressed: {
    subWindow.show()
    ...
}
```

Now, the next thing is to find the correct methods to call. First of all, the QML Window type does not have such method as `forceActiveFocus()`. If you pay some attention to the application output, you should see:

> TypeError: Property 'forceActiveFocus' of object QQuickWindowQmlImpl(0x1a6253d9c50) is not a function

The documentation contains a list of available methods: [Window QML type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#methods). You might want to try a combination of `show()` and `requestActivate()`.

```
Keys.onReturnPressed: {
    subWindow.show()
    subWindow.requestActivate()
}
```

Then, you want to handle keys in the sub-window. Currently, you're trying to attach QML Keys to the Window. Again, if you pay attention to the application output, you should see:

> Could not attach Keys property to:  QQuickWindowQmlImpl(0x1ddb75d7fe0)  is not an Item

Maybe it's just the simplified test-case, but you need to get these things right when you give a testcase, to avoid people focusing on wrong errors. Anyway, what you want to do is to create an item, request focus, and handle keys on it:

```
Window {
    id: subWindow

    Item {
        focus: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: subWindow.close()
    }
}
```

Finally, to put the pieces together, a working minimal testcase would look something like:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    GridView {
        focus: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        // ...
        Keys.onReturnPressed: {
            subWindow.show()
            subWindow.requestActivate()
        }
    }

    Window {
        id: subWindow
        Item {
            focus: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            Keys.onReturnPressed: subWindow.close()
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Key events rely on focus being in where you expect it to be. This may not always be true, if the user tab-navigates focus elsewhere, for example. Consider using the [Shortcut QML type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html) for a more reliable way to close the popup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.